# QUnit test returning "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, qunit

I have some sample code from Glen Johnson's book *Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3*.

My 'app code' is as follows:

```
// Demo of how implementing inheritance works

var Vehicle = (function () {
    function Vehicle(year, make, model) {
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }

    Vehicle.prototype.getInfo = function () {
        return this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model;
    };

    Vehicle.prototype.startEngine = function () {
        return 'Vroom';
    };

    return Vehicle;
})();

var Car = (function (parent) {
    Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
    Car.prototype.constructor = Car;

    function Car(year, make, model) {
        this.wheelQuantity = 4;
        parent.call(this, year, make, model);
    }

    Car.prototype.getInfo = function () {
        return 'Vehicle Type: Car ' + parent.prototype.getInfo.call(this);
    };

    return Car;
})(Vehicle);

var Boat = (function (parent) {
    Boat.prototype = new Vehicle();
    Boat.prototype.constructor = Boat;

    function Boat(year, make, model) {
        this.propellerBladeQuality = 3;
        parent.call(this, year, make, model);
    }

    Boat.prototype.getInfo = function() {
        return 'Vehicle Type: Boat' + parent.prototype.getInfo.call(this);
    }
})(Vehicle);
```

My tests are as follows:

```
module("Implementing Inheritance", {});

test('Creating a Vehicle', function () {
    expect(2);
    var actual,
        expected,
        v = new Vehicle(2012, 'Toyota', 'Rav4');
    actual = v.getInfo();
    expected = '2012 Toyota Rav4';

    equal(expected, actual);

    actual = v.startEngine();
    expected = 'Vroom';
    equal(expected, actual);
});

test('Create a Car', function () {
    expect(5);

    var expectedYear = 2012,
        expectedMake = 'Toyota',
        expectedModel = 'Rav4',
        c = new Car(expectedYear, expectedMake, expectedModel);

    equal(c.year, expectedYear, 'Year');
    equal(c.make, expectedMake, 'Make');
    equal(c.model, expectedModel, 'Model');
    equal(c.wheelQuantity, 4, 'wheelQuality');
    equal(c.getInfo(), 'Vehicle Type: Car ' + expectedYear + ' ' + expectedMake + ' ' + expectedModel, 'getInfo()');
});

test('Create a Boat', function () {
    expect(5);

    var expectedYear = 12334,
        expectedMake = 'dummy-make',
        expectedModel = 'dummy-model',
        expectedPropellerBladeQuality = 3,
        b = new Boat(expectedYear, expectedMake, expectedModel);

    equal(b.year, expectedYear, 'Year');
    equal(b.make, expectedMake, 'Make');
    equal(b.model, expectedModel, 'Model');
    equal(b.propellerBladeQuality, expectedPropellerBladeQuality, 'propellerBladeQuality');
    equal(b.getInfo(), 'Vehicle Type: Boat ' + expectedYear + ' ' + expectedMake + ' ' + expectedModel, 'getInfo()');
});
```

When they are run, the *Create a Car* test passes, however the *Create a Boat* test fails with the following exception:

```
Died on test #1     at file:///C://JavaScript_Samples/tests/implementingInheritance.js:33:1: undefined is not a function
Source:     
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/JavaScript_Samples/tests/implementingInheritance.js:40:13)
```

I can't see the reason for this, the code for both the `Car` and the `Boat` seem identical to me.

I've tried this in Chrome and Firefox, the results are the same in both.

Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement for the created `Boat` class:

```
var Boat = (function (parent) {
    Boat.prototype = new Vehicle();
    Boat.prototype.constructor = Boat;

    function Boat(year, make, model) {
        this.propellerBladeQuality = 3;
        parent.call(this, year, make, model);
    }

    Boat.prototype.getInfo = function() {
        return 'Vehicle Type: Boat' + parent.prototype.getInfo.call(this);
    }

    // insert return statement here
    return Boat;
})(Vehicle);
```